# Multiple URL referral spam list

Tags: google-analytics, spam

As a company, we're running a homepage with a set of landing pages (10+ of them) and it's becoming quite tedious to keep updating a spam referral list on every one of them individually.

Is it possible to setup ONE exclusion list? Also, is it possible to have this exclusion list update automatically, or is there a source of spammy URL's which we can add in?

Comment: Can you explain *keep updating a spam referral list on every one of them individually* more please. Are you using a tool? Are you using .htaccess? What are you talking about? This may help.

Comment: Hi, I'm just manually picking of spam referrals from the audience acquisition list and adding them to an exclude filter. The issue is, I have 3 exclusion filters per site now as there's so much spam. That's what's taking up all the time.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is a way to automatically add spam referrers to your filters since it requires a level of human involvement to decide what is real and what is spam especially with the more recent language spam which mimics real site URLs. There are [sites](https://referrerspamblocker.com/blacklist) that keep a running tab of spam sites.

The 3 filters included in the instructions [here](https://www.ohow.co/ultimate-guide-to-removing-irrelevant-traffic-in-google-analytics/) have completely removed referral spam from my Google Analytics accounts.  #1 & #2 filter crawler spam and #3 Filters language spam. I think the language spam filter is important with this new spam technique and will probably not need to be updated as often.

1. (best|dollar|success|top1)-seo|(videos|buttons)-for|anticrawler|^scripted.|semalt|forum69|7makemon|sharebutton|ranksonic|sitevaluation|dailyrank|vitaly|profit.xyz|rankings-|dbutton|uptime(bot|check|.com)
2. datract|hacĸer|ɢoogl|responsive-test|dogsrun|tkpass|free-video|keywords-monitoring|pr-cy.ru|fix-website|checkpagerank|seo-2-0.|platezhka|timer4web|share-buttons|99seo|3-letter
3. \s[^\s]*\s|.{15,}|.|,

Comment: Piwik [blocks referrer spam by default for several years now](https://piwik.org/blog/2015/05/stopping-referrer-spam/), and maintains a free blacklist you can use with other analytics providers that lack this capability. Click through to their GitHub page to see specific server configs and how to automate updating the filters.